# best way to refractor this code?

Tags: java, android, json

```
package com.example.moviesearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class ParseJSON {
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    private String genres;
    private String rated;
    private String language;
    private int rating;
    private String country;
    private String release_date;
    private String title;
    private String directors;
    private String actors;
    private String plot_simple;
    private String poster;
    private String runtime;
    private String imdb_url;

    public ArrayList<Movie> parseJson(String json) {
        movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                try {
                    genres = j.getString("genres").replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "").replaceAll("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    genres = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    rated = j.getString("rated");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    rated = "not found";
                }
                try {
                    language = j.getString("language").replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "").replaceAll("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    language = "notfound";
                }

                try {
                    rating = j.getInt("rating");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    rating = 404;
                }

                try {
                    country = j.getString("country").replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "").replaceAll("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    country = "not found";
                }
                try {
                    release_date = j.getString("release_date");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    release_date = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    title = j.getString("title").replace("\n", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    title = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    directors = j.getString("directors").replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "").replaceAll("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    directors = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    actors = j.getString("actors").replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "").replaceAll("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    actors = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    plot_simple = j.getString("plot_simple");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    poster = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    JSONObject c = j.getJSONObject("poster");
                    poster = c.getString("cover");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    poster = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    runtime = j.getString("runtime").replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "").replaceAll("\"", "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    runtime = "notfound";
                }
                try {
                    imdb_url = j.getString("imdb_url");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    imdb_url = "notfound";
                }
                Movie movie = new Movie(genres, rated, language, rating,
                        country, release_date, title, directors, actors,
                        plot_simple, poster, runtime, imdb_url);
                movies.add(movie);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("jsonerror", "", e);
        }
        return movies;
    }
}
```

I am making an android app and needing to parse json data. I turn this json data into a custom Class. Sometimes the json I parse doesn't exist so I have to put in a default value for it, I feel this is too brute.

Comment: LOL! Arent't questions supposed to have *question marks*?

Comment: I don't see how reg exp will help. Either way I have to check if the json exists. Can you provide an example maybe I am misunderdstanding

Comment: One try-catch with multiple necessary exceptions, learn ternary, and try optString() method where appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a method

```
j.optString("imdb_url", "notfound");
```

where you can pass some default value for the case the value is not found - so you don't have to catch the exception after every getString